# Best way to stop a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using a thread in a thread pool to do some actions. 
Now, in some cases, if something goes wrong, I want to close the form. 
I have a try/catch-block and if it catches something, it should do something and then close the form. The problem is, when is closed, the thread goes on in the background and then throws an exception on a place where I invoke something, because the handle is not there anymore.

Well, so I need to stop the thread, so that it does not continue. I heard 'Abort' is not a good solution, well I should make a flag variable and make a query, but how should I do this?
Is there maybe a better way?
If you need code, tell me, but it is more a general question.

Thanks!

Comment: Search on Msdn "cancellation Token" and if you started an async process you should stop with its oppoısite of start method..i.e. if there is an Async read (System.IO binary or text reader or something else) started with BeginRead static method it should end by EndRead Method..

Comment: If an exception is thrown, then - unless it is explicitly caught - it should bubble up to and terminate the main thread loop, so it seems that there should be no need to do anything special.

Comment: [Using Cancellation Support in .NET Framework 4](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/C/F/BCFD4868-1354-45E3-B71B-B851CD78733D/UsingCancellationinNET4.pdf). Also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/22/9635790.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the problem, because you didn't provide the code, but maybe you should check InvokeRequired property, try this:

```
if (Control.InvokeRequired)
{
// your code
}
```

Comment: It is not about if I need to invoke. Problem is, the thread goes on in the background, when the form is already closed ;).

Answer (score 1):

I usually have a flag which gets set to true when the form is closing, or when I need the thread to terminate for any other reason.

Another helpful thing to do is to set the `IsBackground` property to `true`, which makes the process terminate when the last form closes, rather than leaving a phantom process running.

For example, if you have a form that spawns a thread which periodically does a calculation in a `while (true)`, you must manually terminate the thread somehow when the form closes. If you set `IsBackground = true`, then the thread will not prevent the process from terminating.

(However, of course, you should also keep in mind that if the thread somehow interacts with the form, then you need to handle that, otherwise closing the form will likely cause an exception in the thread when it's no longer able to access disposed objects, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure your thread executes to the end properly and clean. After this you can close your form and delete your thread object.

This is how I generally handle all of my threads. I use a bunch of "signal" variables (that I define in their own class) to allow me to control my thread and check on it's status from the application thread. If you try and catch something, that's awesome! just "abort" the function by falling completely out until its running idle. After the thread is completely finished you can delete it safely.

```
    void MyThreadFunction () {
      bThreadActive = true;

      while(!bThreadTerminate){
        bThreadIdle = false;  //thread is no longer idle.
        bThreadStart = false; //Reset this too 

        //Do all your thread stuff here.
          doSomething();

        while(!bThreadTerminate){
          //Stay here until we start or terminate
          bThreadIdle = true;

          if(bThreadStart)
            break;
        }
      }

      bThreadActive = false;
    }

    void doSomething(){
      //Anytime you go into a loop and if statements, check if it's been terminated.
      //When you set bThreadTerminate to true, exit the thread without any further calculations.
      //Any logical statement needs to also check if you want to terminate the thread.

      int iNum1 = 1;
      int iNum2 = 1;

      try {
        if(iNum1 == iNum2 && !bThreadTerminate){
        //Stuff to do.
        }
      }catch(Exception *e){
        //Abort Code here
      }
    }
```

So basically, this will perform all operations once, and wait until you need to do it again (on your call). You set bStart to true and it will loop all the way through until it's idle again. If you set bThreadTerminate to true then on your main thread you would wait until bActive is false before you delete it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, it's a good answer, but I solved it the other way.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23463189/2725299

But still thanks, got an upvote ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I managed to do it, the task is actually very simple.

You have to declare a *CancellationTokenSource* and an *Action* for the void/function to execute.
Like that:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
Action yourAction;
```

Then initialize the action with the void to execute:

```
yourAction = anyvoid;
```

And finally:

```
yourAction.BeginInvoke(yourAction.EndInvoke, null);
```

That is how you start it.
Now, when you need to cancel/stop the thread, you go ahead and say:

```
cancellationToken.Cancel();
```

After that it will cancel the thread.
To avoid the thread is going on during that time, just make a query after all "Cancelling"-executions.

```
if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
  return;
```

That's it. The advantage is, you do not have to handle any AbortExceptions or anything and this is imo a clean way to stop a thread.